# Right Derivative of the Norm

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification, banach-spaces

$
 \newcommand{\D}{\mathrm{D}}
 \newcommand{\r}{\mathrm{r}}
$
This question concerns problem 3.5.2 from [Cartan's Differential Calculus](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZFgZAQAAIAAJ&q=cartan+differential+calculus).

Let $E$ denote a real Banach space and $[a,b]$ be an interval of the real line.

We say that the function $f : [a,b] \to E$ is differentiable at the right at point $t \in [a,b)$ if the limit
$$
\lim_{s \downarrow t} \frac{f(s) - f(t)}{s - t} = \D_\r f|_t
$$
exists ($s \downarrow t$ represents convergence from above).

Here is the problem:

> Prove theat if $f$ is right-differentiable at $t$ then the function $g = \| f \|$ is also right-differentiable at $t$.

My proof goes:

By definition of right-differentiability and convergence in Banach space it follows that

$$
0 = \lim_{s \downarrow t} \frac{\| f(s) - f(t) -\D_\r f |_t (s -t) \|}{s - t}
$$
which along with the fact that in any normed space $\| x - y \| \ge | \|x\| - \|y\| |$ provides
$$
(1) \quad 0 \ge \lim_{s \downarrow t} \frac{\Big| \|f(s)\| -\|f(t) +\D_\r f|_t(s - t)\|   \Big|}{s - t} \ge^*
\inf_{u \in \mathbb{R}} \lim_{s \downarrow t}
\frac{\Big| g(s) - g(t) - u(s - t)  \Big|}{s -t} \ge 0.
$$
Last expression must be equal  to zero as it clearly non-negative. Now we want to show that minimizer $u$ exists:
$$
 \lim_{s \downarrow t}\frac {| g(s) - g(t) | } {s -t} \le \lim_{s \downarrow t} \frac{\| f(s) - f(t) \|}{s - t} = \| \D_\r f|_t  \|
$$
by continuity of the norm. Hence we can safely minimize over compact interval $\Big[
-\| \D_\r f|_t \|, \| \D_r f |_t \| \Big]$ which shows that minimizer $u$ exists. This shows that $g$ has right differential $u$ at $t$. $\square$

I have a problem with $(\ge^*)$ transition in (1). it seems to be right,
but I son't know how to handle transition from $\| f(t) + \D_\r f|_t(s -t) \| $ to $ g(t) + \D_\r g |_t$.

What the correct proof would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider linear $f$ first: $f(s) = As+B$. Then $\|f\|$ is a convex function, so [one-sided derivatives exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1408231).

General case: $f$ has right derivative $A$ at $t$, meaning $$f(s) = f(t)+A(s-t)+o(|s-t|),\quad s\to t^+$$ Since the norm is a Lipschitz function, it follows that $$\|f(s)\| = \|f(t)+A(s-t)\| + o(|s-t|),\quad s\to t^+$$
Here  $\|f(t)+A(s-t)\|$ is right-differentiable by the linear case, and the $o$-term is negligible.